# Can't use Handlebars to generate class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using Ember.js with a Rails app, but when I want to dynamically change class name depending on the data, I get an error. Here is the Handlebars file:

```
<ul id="data-all" class="list-items">
  {{#each datum in data}}
    <li class="list-item">
      {{#link-to 'data.datum' datum.name classNames="link-item"}}
        <span class="datum-last-action datum-{{datum.name}}">{{datum.name}}</span>
      {{/link-to}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

And the generated errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: An error occured while setting up template bindings. Please check for invalid markup or bindings within HTML comments.
Uncaught Error: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.
```

All the doc I found don't give special warning using this, so why does this occure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. If you're using Ember<=1.9.1, then it should be:

```
<span {{bind-attr class=":datum-last-action datumName}}">{{datum.name}}</span>
```

where `datumName` is a computed property in your controller / component:

`:datum-last-action` means the same as "if false, do nothing, otherwise print `datum-last-action`.

When you iterate over an array, you can use mapped property for the whole data object. In your controller, create a computed property like that:

```
proxiedData: Ember.computed.map('data', function(datum, index) {
  return Ember.ObjectProxy.create({
    name: datum.name,
    className: "datum-" + datum.name
  });
}),
```

and then, in handlebars:

```
<ul id="data-all" class="list-items">
  {{#each datum in proxiedData}}
    <li class="list-item">
      {{#link-to 'data.datum' datum.name classNames="link-item"}}
        <span {{bind-attr class=":datum-last-action datum.className"}}>{{datum.name}}</span>
      {{/link-to}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @andrusieczko for your reply. Indeed, I'm using Ember version 1.9.1 with ember-rails gem. The class name I have is always `datum-last-action` without the `datumName` property, but this is maybe because I don't use an Ember controller, right?

Comment: Hey, this is what I meant - you should create a datumName property in the controller in order to be able to use it in `bind-attr class` helper.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check if now it makes more sense

Comment: Thank @andrusieczko. It works now :) Don't understand why we can't use Handlebars directly in the class name (or generally in any attribute), seems easier (more natural) than using a controller!

Comment: it's all because they want to avoid any logic in the templates which in long term makes a lot of sense! remember that you could always create a `list-item` controller to avoid these complicated computed properties - then, you can just pass the single model to that controller